# Fixing permissions on home directory

Tags: permissions

So I was following a guide (incorrectly) and mindlessly ended up giving owner permissions to my home directory (`/home/username`) to a different group (or user, not sure which is which). I figured out how to get myself owner back, but now it seems like I have a bunch of messed up permissions with directories inside my home directory. For example Flatpak apps which are installed in `~/. local/share/flatpak` no longer open. How can I revert back to how everything was before?

Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo chown -R plex: /home/username
```

Then using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/35076/need-to-fix-file-permissions-in-a-users-home-directory) as a reference I did the following:

```
sudo chown -R username:username  /home/username
find /home/username -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
find /home/username -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

Comment: You can just run `sudo chown -R userid:groupid /home/username`. In this command, `userid` should be presumably the same with `username`. Please, first check the `userid` and the `groupid` using the command `id` (run the `id` command with your _current user_; not using `sudo`). _`userid`_ should be the value given in `uid=` _userid_ and _`groupid`_ should be the value given in `gid=` _groupid_.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is not a way to magically put permissions back to the way they were before a change made by command line (or GUI actually).  And as far as I know there would not be anything other than your username applied to permissions inside your /home/username folder.

However, what I expect has happened, is in your first command (the one where you applied the Plex owner to the files) you've applied to all files including hidden files that start with a '.'.

In the second command I suspect it doesn't put your username back on the hidden files, i.e. only the files that start without a dot.

If you want to check it first, just do:

```
# cd /home/username
# ls -lah
```

Then look for the user / group ownership on the hidden files. If any of them are still showing as Plex, then you know this is the issue.

To fix this there would be a number of ways, but I'd just do something like

```
# cd /home/username
# chown . username.group -Rfv.
```

Starting with a . like that will apply the ownership to the hidden files as well because it is just saying, "start the apply here, where I already am in /home/username".